# Am I initiating jQuery.masonry more than once per ajax request?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-masonry

I have the following script which works, but I don't think it's a nice way of doing it:

```
success: function( widget_shell ) 
{ 

    if( widget_shell.d[0] ) {

        $( "#container" ).empty();

        var i = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i <= widget_shell.d.length - 1; i++ ) {

            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 50

            var $widget = $( "<div class='item col1' style='height:" + j + "px'></div>" ).appendTo( $( "#container" ) );
            $( "<span>" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id + " - " + j + "</span>" ).appendTo( $widget );

        }

        $('#container').masonry({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            columnWidth: 240
        });

        $('#container').masonry('reload')

    }

}
```

My main concern is the `.masonry` part.  As the `success` happens many times, i.e. per ajax request, I think the code above is re-initiating the `.masonry` each time and then reloading it.

I have tried moving the `.masonry` initiation outside and above the function which contains the `success`, but that seems to try to initialise the `.masonry` before the `div`s are created, so it doesn't work.

Any suggestions, or is this a good way of going about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you bother with that if it works? I wouldn't. You can use Jquery template plugin. Maybe it's a bit faster the just DOM. Look in my signature  for an example with masonry.

Comment: Current website I have is extremely slow at rendering on clientside, so I am trying to do as much as possible to speed it up.  serverside is all based on returning json data so that part is fast, however the clientside is jquery heavy and clunky.

Answer (score 0):

You could test that, not sure it works for masonry plugin:

```
if($().masonry == 'undefined')
$('#container').masonry({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            columnWidth: 240
        });

$('#container').masonry('reload')
```

Comment: Just tried this, and it seems to stop `.masonry` from doing its thing altogether.